# INSERT from SELECT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, select, insert, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to run an INSERT query, based upon a SELECT, with an "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" statement. The SELECT query works, and the resulting data if I were to input it "manually" will result in a duplicate key issue. So far so good. However, the query below does not seem to update the value in "et_report_ymd.quotes" as I expected it to do.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO et_report_ymd
SELECT 
    NULL,
    t.year AS year,
    t.month AS month,
    t.day AS day,
    SUM(t.quotes) AS quotes

FROM source_table AS t

GROUP BY t.year, t.month, t.day

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    et_report_ymd.quotes = quotes
```

All help is welcome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And just when you decided to ask for help, you come up with the solution, as always.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO et_report_ymd
SELECT 
    NULL,
    t.year AS year,
    t.month AS month,
    t.day AS day,
    SUM(t.quotes) AS quotes

FROM source_table AS t

GROUP BY t.year, t.month, t.day

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
et_report_ymd.quotes = VALUES(quotes)
```

Note the "VALUES(quotes)" part at the end of the query instead of just "quotes".